# Display only specific information in hovertext of radarchart

Tags: r, radar-chart

I create the radarchart below and I would like to know if it is possible to exclude all the person with `value=6` from the hoverinfo text.

```
library(radarchart)

# Using the data frame interface
chartJSRadar(scores=skills)

# Or using a list interface
labs <- c("Communicator", "Data Wangler", "Programmer", "Technologist",  "Modeller", "Visualizer")

scores <- list("Rich" = c(9, 7, 4, 5, 3, 7),
               "Andy" = c(7, 6, 6, 2, 6, 9),
               "Aimee" = c(6, 5, 8, 4, 7, 6))

# Default settings
chartJSRadar(scores=scores, labs=labs)
```